# Cannot bulk load. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

For some weird reason I'm having problems executing a bulk insert.

```
BULK INSERT customer_stg
FROM 'C:\Users\Michael\workspace\pydb\data\andrew.out.txt'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW=0,
    FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
)
```

I'm confident after reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms189934(v=sql.90)) that I've setup my user role correctly, as it states...

> Members of the bulkadmin fixed server role can run the BULK INSERT statement.

I have set the `Login Properties` for the Windows Authentication correctly (as seen below).. to grant server-wide permissions on `bulkadmin`

[image: windows authentication]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/daaqcasj.vo1.png))</sub>

And the command `EXEC sp_helpsrvrolemember 'bulkadmin'` tells me that the information above was successful, and the current user `Michael-PC\Michael` has `bulkadmin` permissions.

[image: bulkadmin]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/bou0uklk.wdj.png))</sub>

But even though I've set everything up correctly as far as I know, I'm still getting the error. executing the bulk insert directly from SQL Server Management Studio.

> *Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\Michael\workspace\pydb\data\andrew.out.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).*

which doesn't make sense because apparently `bulkadmins` can run the statement, am I meant to reconfigure how the `bulkadmin` works? (I'm so lost). Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is external to SQL Server. Can you open the file in Notepad?

Comment: Yeah I can open it in Notepad.

Comment: If the server is not local, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/afd79cab-405f-4e81-bff6-2c40b97e3c8e could be relevant

Comment: for now I'm just going to try and do a fresh install of SQL Server, as it just doesn't make logical sense in why I'm being restricted from accessing a file.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what to say, sorry. Good luck!

Comment: Can you set the path to the file in a way that it is accessible from the network, say "Michael-PC\C$\...\Andrew.out.txt" and pass this to the command line?

Comment: Solomon Rutzky's answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208181/bulk-insert-getting-cannot-bulk-load-because-access-is-denied-on-a-file-i helped me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple the way I resolved this problem:

1. open SQL Server
2. right click on database (you want to be backup)
3. select properties
4. select permissions
5. select your database role (local or cloud)
6. in the you bottom you will see explicit permissions table
7. find "  backup database " permission and click Grant permission .

your problem is resolved .

Answer (score 30):

This error appears when you are using SQL Server Authentication and SQL Server is not allowed to access the bulk load folder.

So giving SQL server access to the folder will solve the issue.
[image]

Here is how to:
Go to the folder right click ->properties->Security tab->Edit->Add(on the new window) ->Advanced -> Find Now. Under the users list in the search results, find something like SQLServerMSSQLUser$UserName$SQLExpress and click ok, to all the dialogs opened.

Comment: I couldn't find the correct account to grant access to, but as I was just trying to load a file from my development machine, I granted read permission on the file to "Everyone" (that's what I entered as the account name / principal).

Comment: necro, but there's official documentation, which may be easier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access - basically, add the NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER user

Comment: I couldn't figure out which user to add the permissions to either, so just used Everyone. I can't find a user called "NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER"

Comment: where the heck is the "bulk load folder"? Is that meaning the folder in which the file you are trying to load is stored?

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe yes bulk load folder just means the folder where the file is you're BULK INSERTing. For me adding permissions to the folder for the user called  SERVICE worked.

Comment: Go to Sql Server Configuration Manager  -> Sql Server Services ->  right click on Sql Server -> Properties, under the Account Name copy that name and add it into Add window in file explorer.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think reinstalling SQL Server is going to fix this, it's just going to kill some time.

1. Confirm that your user account has read privileges to the folder in question.
2. Use a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what user is actually trying to access the file.
3. My guess is that it is not `Michael-PC\Michael` that is trying to access the file, but rather the SQL Server service account. If this is the case, then you have at least three options (but probably others):

   a. Set the SQL Server service to run as you.

   b. Grant the SQL Server service account explicit access to that folder.

   c. Put the files somewhere more logical where SQL Server has access, or can be made to have access (e.g. `C:\bulk\`).

I suggest these things assuming that this is a contained, local workstation. There are definitely more serious security concerns around local filesystem access from SQL Server when we're talking about a production machine, of course this can still be largely mitigated by using `c.` above - and only giving the service account access to the folders you want it to be able to touch.

Comment: Its just a machine that I'm using to build and test the software, not the production system.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to start run=>services.msc=>SQL SERVER(MSSQLSERVER) stop the service
2. Right click on SQL SERVER(MSSQLSERVER)=> properties=>LogOn Tab=>Local System Account=>OK
3. Restart the SQL server Management Studio.

Comment: Out of all of the numerous suggested solutions I have found on the web, this one actually solved my problem. Thank you, @Vinay Patel

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem SSIS 2012 and the solution was to use Windows Authentication. I was using SQL authentication with the sa user.

Comment: Quickest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try giving the folder(s) containing the CSV and Format File read permissions for ‘MSSQLSERVER’ user (or whatever user the SQL Server service is set to **Log On As** in **Windows Services**)

Comment: thanks a lot - following @antew 's answer I tried for find `SQL` or `MSSQL` in the list but can't. I see `MSSQL` is `log on as` "local service" in `windows service`. I added "local service" to security and fixed the permission issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

Log on SSIS with Windows authentication.

**1.** Open services and find MSSQL NT Service account name and copy it:

[image]

**2.** Open folder from which SQL server should read from. **Security - Group or user names tab - Add** and paste there copied account:**

[image]

3. You will probably get "Multiple names found error", just select MSSQL user:

[image]

Your `BULK INSERT` query should run fine now.
If problem persists try adding SQL Server Agent account to folder permissions in same way.
Make sure you restart MSSQL server in services after you are done.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes this can be a bogus error message, tried opening the file with the same account that it is running the process.  I had the same issue in my environment and when I did open the file (with the same credentials running the process), it said that it must be associated with a known program, after I did that I was able to open it and run the process without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the file you're using (`'C:\Users\Michael\workspace\pydb\data\andrew.out.txt'`) is on the SQL server machine and not the client machine running MSSMS.

Comment: The client machine is the sql server (development machine)

Comment: VERY good point

Answer (score 1):

1) Open SQL 
2) In Task Manager, you can check which account is running the SQL - it is probably not Michael-PC\Michael as Jan wrote.

The account that runs SQL need access to the shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have come to similar question when I execute the bulk insert in SSMS it's working but it failed and returned with "Operation system failure code 5" when converting the task into SQL Server Agent.

After browsing lots of solutions posted previously, this way solved my problem by granting the NT SERVER/SQLSERVERAGENT with the 'full control" access right to the source folder.
Hope it would bring some light to these people who are still struggling with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

In our case it ended up being a Kerberos issue.  I followed the steps in this article to resolve the issue: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server-Support/Bulk-Insert-and-Kerberos/ba-p/317304.

It came down to configuring delegation on the machine account of the SQL Server where the BULK INSERT statement is running.  The machine account needs to be able to delegate via the "cifs" service to the file server where the files are located.  If you are using constrained delegation make sure to specify "Use any authenication protocol".

If DFS is involved you can execute the following Powershell command to get the name of the file server:

```
Get-DfsnFolderTarget -Path "\\dfsnamespace\share"
```