# Newly created CSV file has error during BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv, vb.net-2010

I would like to ask for your help.

I created a program that would retrieve a data from a CSV file, read selected rows, and then create a CSV file with the data that was selected. After that, the system would then upload the data from the newly created file to the database, which ends the transaction.

the problem is when doing the BULK INSERT, the database throws and error

```
operating system error code 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. reason: 15105)
```

After researching, I found out that this was a permission issue, or is it?

Here is what I have done so far.

```
ALTER DATABASE training SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

I also added `FIRE_TRIGGERS` on my BULK INSERT

do take note that I am using SA account and I would like to upload it to my local database (the deployment would be on our live servers)

do also take not that inserting the data from SQL using the stored procedure which I have created is working.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi How big file is this.. i doubt there is space issue.

Comment: Its 938 bytes of data sir.

Comment: try to give full access on file /folder  to user under whose sql service is running...

Comment: could It be done in SQL or in VB.Net?

Comment: can be just right click and permission ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555262/cannot-bulk-load-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this error is indeed a permission error, as stated by @sandeep rawat, and you may use his answer if you will. I would like to share with you what I did if you would want to do this in your system.

First of, I would like to apologize of some lacking points which may have been critical and necessary in answering this question.
1) I forgot to mention that, the system is created and saved in My computer, which has a domain and a admin, my user account would need a admin access to change anything.(thus again, it is a permission error)

2) The stored procedure that I have created DOES NOT WORK WHEN I TRY TO BULK LOAD THE DATA FROM MY USER ACCOUNT. I tried to use the stored procedure with the following code

```
BULK INSERT temptable
    FROM 'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestUploader\TestUploader\bin\Debug\MyCSV.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    MAXERRORS = 100,
    FIRSTROW = 2
    )
```

And It did not work, It gives out the error which is stated in the question.

So here's what I did.

1)I imported system.security.accessControl

```
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
```

2)I created a Folder under C:\

```
Dim folderName As String
folderName = "C:\CSVUPLOADS\"

'check if folder exists, if not, create folder
           If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderName)) Then
               System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName)
           End If
```

3) Grant Access to the folder

```
 Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(folderName)
                Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
                FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow))
                FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

4) then I recreated the file from the original location, and put it in the new folder.

```
 fileName = "dataUpload.csv"
fileName = folderName & fileName

'Create CSV file
                File.Create(fileName).Dispose()
```

After the steps I have created above, I could now read the CSV file, even in the deployment environment.

The advantage of these steps is, you don't have to add permissions to certain folders.

The disadvantage would be, I have to create a system that would create, copy and locate the CSV file which I need to another location.

Do take note that I have created a system for this, not just a SQL script, so the above code is incomplete. The above code only discusses the creation of a new folder and a new CSV file that could be read by SQL without you giving it permissions manually. So If you opt to do this, you have to research on how to get the data from the CSV file to the new CSV file, call stored procedures, and then do bulk insert.

P.S - I'm not marking this as a answer, but only as a option because the real answer is permissions.