# Adding file image to SQL Server 2014 causes error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error trying to insert an image into SQL Server. The number of the specified column match the given value I provided.

> Msg 120, Level 15, State 1, Line 152
>   The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

The insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Residents (FName, MName, LName, 
                       BDate, BPlace, BOrder, Age, 
                       CStatusID, Gender, Religion, Nationality, 
                       BloodType, ContactNo, Photo)
    SELECT
        'Racel', 'Palomares', 'Ruperez', 
        '1999-05-10', 'Negros', 3, 18, 
        1 'F', 'Roman Catholic', 'Filipino', 
        'B+', '09173399068', BulkColumn 
    FROM
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\thesisadmin\Downloads\120.jpg', Single_Blob) AS ResidentPicture
```

Comment: Missing comma between `1` and `'F'` .

Comment: Oh yeah
But another error occured:
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 152
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\thesisadmin\Downloads\120.jpg" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555262/cannot-bulk-load-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied

Comment: Can you provide the schema of your table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE Residents(
 ResidentID  INT IDENTITY,
 Photo   VARBINARY(max),
 FName   VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
 MName   VARCHAR(25),
 LName   VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
 BDate   DATE   NOT NULL,
 BPlace   VARCHAR(max),
 BOrder   TINYINT,
 Age    TINYINT   NOT NULL,
 CStatusID  INT REFERENCES CivilStatus(CivilStatusID),
 Gender   CHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
 Religion  VARCHAR(max),
 Nationality  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
 BloodType  VARCHAR(10),
 ContactNo  VARCHAR(30),
 PRIMARY KEY(ResidentID)
)

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing a comma between `1` and `'F'`.

```
INSERT INTO 
    Residents(FName, MName, LName, BDate, BPlace, BOrder, Age, CStatusID, 
        Gender, Religion, Nationality, BloodType, ContactNo, Photo)
SELECT 
    'Racel', 'Palomares', 'Ruperez', '1999-05-10', 'Negros', 3, 18, 1, 'F', 
        'Roman Catholic', 'Filipino', 'B+', '09173399068',BulkColumn 
From 
    Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Users\thesisadmin\Downloads\120.jpg', Single_Blob) as ResidentPicture
```

Comment: you can add a few () for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You might try the below script.

```
INSERT INTO Residents
(FName, MName, LName, BDate, 
     BPlace, BOrder, Age, CStatusID, 
     Gender, Religion, Nationality, BloodType, 
     ContactNo, Photo)
SELECT 'Racel', 'Palomares', 'Ruperez', '1999-05-10', 
     'Negros', 3, 18, 1, 'F', 
    'Roman Catholic', 'Filipino',  
    'B+', '09173399068',BulkColumn 
From 
Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Users\thesisadmin\Downloads\120.jpg', Single_Blob) as ResidentPicture
```

I presume, the issue is that you missed a comma between 1 and 'F' in the select statement(8th and 9th parameters).

Comment: yeah. but another error occured :
     Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 156
     Cannot bulk load because the file 
     "C:\Users\thesisadmin\Downloads\120.jpg" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

Comment: Could you try loading the file from the MSSQL Server accessible location?.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is file permissions. The file is accessed by the sqlserver.exe that is running under a service account. Put the file into a SQL Server folder where the service has read access, like

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQL2017\MSSQL\Backup

You will see it can load the file from there.

Long-term: configure NTFS permissions for a given folder.