# BULK Insert error couldn't be open

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to load csv file with header into database. For this I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE rules(
[ApplicableForColumn] [varchar](max) NULL,
[IsUnique] [varchar](max) NULL,
[MinimumLength] [varchar](max) NULL,
[MaximumLength] [varchar](max) NULL,
[IsNumber] [varchar](max) NULL,
[MustHaveOneofFollowing] [varchar](max) NULL,
[PlatformNumber] [varchar](max) NULL  )
```

and for insert I tried this:

```
Bulk insert rules from 'C:\Users\gbd-int\Downloads\rules.csv'
with (
rowterminator ='\n',
fieldterminator= ',',
errorfile='C:\Users\gbd-int\Downloads\rules.csv'
)
```

But I am getting this error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 Cannot bulk load because the file
>   "C:\Users\gbd-int\Downloads\rules.csv" could not be opened. Operating
>   system error code 5(Access is denied.).

And as mention in this link
[Cannot bulk load. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555262/cannot-bulk-load-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied).
I tried both Windows authentication and SqlServer authentication, as well as giving permission for SqlServer from file property.
And I am still getting error.
Please help me solve it.

Comment: `C:\Users\gbd-int\Downloads\rules.csv` this should be present in your server, not in your local machine

Comment: Can you please explain me what you are saying.  I am new to sql server

Comment: `C:\Users\gbd-int\Downloads\rules.csv` is this path present in your local system ?

Comment: Yes...file is in my download folder

Comment: Sql Server service will not have access to your local folder. Copy the file to Sql Server machine or copy the file to some shared location in your network where Sql Server service has access to and place the path in bulk insert.

Comment: Sorry i m just beginner .Can u tell me(Copy the file to Sql Server machine ) How to do it?.( copy the file to some shared location in your network) and where is this location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162859/discussion-between-awesome-and-p).

Comment: Seek the help of your IT/Networking team.