# How to make a local folder seen by SQL Server 2016 and type into the correct path

Tags: json, sql-server

I have multiple json files to import into SQL Server 2016. I can do it in my local environment, but the code does not work when I run it in the real server. Error message reports that "the network path was not found", "access denied", 'The system cannot find the path specified'.

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET
     (BULK '\\**.**.**.**\C$\folder\1234.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j
```

I have three questions:

1. whether the format within `()` is correct, IP address plus the physical address in my local computer, if it's incorrect, please correct me
2. which IP address should I use, my local IP or the localhost "127.0.0.1";
3. the folder has already been shared, not sure why it cannot be found. I am new to this topic.

Some questions may be naive. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should check user name, which runs Sql server service in Sql Server Configuration Manager and give proper access to that user on that shared folder

Comment: Thanks, I share that folder to everyone with "read" permission. Not sure if it is correct

Comment: No I still cannot figure it out. Thanks for followup anyway. Frankly, I am even not sure how to check user name, lol. I followed this link, but it doesn't work either. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555262/cannot-bulk-load-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied

Comment: I use this query to check the user name:SELECT CURRENT_USER. The folder has already been shared with that user. Do not know why it's still inaccessible.Could you give me more suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Log in to you server, where Sql Server is installed, open
Sql Server 201X Configuration Manager (MMC), in Services Section find Sql Server (MSSQLSERVER), click properties and look for a login on Login Tab there. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-change-the-service-startup-account?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Here is the user name "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER". I think it's default for every server. But I cannot find it by "check names" when adding new user name

Comment: Can you create another user, run MS Sql Server with it And give rights to that user?

Comment: I gave up this way. Alternatively, try to create a shared folder in server and then move files over there. Thanks.

Comment: You won't find a user NT Service\MSSQLSERVER in "check names", yes.But this question is already answered here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e6bb2de-8fd0-45de-ab02-d59bbe05f72e/servicedatabase-accounts-nt-servicemssqlserver-amp-nt-servicesqlserveragent-8230-what-are?forum=sqlsecurity