# Problem with SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio. Worked on server with remote access

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I get this exception:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
> Cannot bulk load because the file "\folder\input.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

However, this query worked, and suddenly this exception appeared.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: This is a permissions issue or a file system mounting issue.  You need to be sure the SQL Server server has access to the file.

Comment: Which logical drive do you expect SQL Server to be using with your relative path reference? And which is it using now vs. which WAS it using when it worked?

Comment: SQL Server is working on this specific file for the last 15 months, with this specific path, and every time take data from this specific file. I cannot realize the problem. And till now every solution on StackOverflow has not worked.

Comment: If it *suddenly* stopped working, what *suddenly* changed? Are you using a different user, did a different user create the file or take ownership? Is it still open by another application, such as Excel? What *are* the permissions on the file? I assume the file is on a local driver of the server (as opposed to being on the client PC)

Comment: Have you checked security permissions to the file location and the file itself - the account sqlserver is running as needs read permission. Have you checked you can open the file, it's not corrupt or locked by another application. Have you (seriously) tried turning it off and on again.

Comment: @sTTu seriously all the above

Comment: @Charlieface. same user as always. i checked it and from another user. file is on the same older as always with same permission. maybe i need to talk with an admin rights user for further details. thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Try a different file in the same location, try using a different method to access it other than bulk load eg openrowset / xp_cmdshell / CLR method. If access denied still then it's definitely file system permissions, or share permissions if you are using one (or both)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably permission related issue. The user you are using to bulk load might no more have permission to access that files.

For some further clarification you might browse below link:

[Cannot bulk load. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555262/cannot-bulk-load-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied)