# Insert image query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a table like this.

```
 myID   Name     Pic
   1     Shan    
   2     Sharon
```

myId column is integer type, Name is varchar(10) and pic is type of image data type. I'm using SQL Server.

In a normal insert procedure, in which if you don't have a column name of data type "image" I know the insert would look like this.

```
      INSERT INTO myTable
      VALUES (1,Shan);
```

How to insert image data type column how to select the file. How to write an insert query to a table which is having a image data type column?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bummi column type is not binary or blob, it's image data type.

Comment: They are all stored binary [ntext, text, and image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)   `if 
(Select CAST(PICAsImage as Varbinary(max)) from PICS where ID=1)
=
(Select PICAsVarBinary from PICS where ID=2)
print 'true'` will print true if the same image was loaded via `OPENROWSET(BULK `

Comment: @bummi I didn't want a casted answer, I just asked a simple query, with a simple explanation if could. i don't understand what you are talking about. i just wanted to know how to set file path for the image.

Comment: It's shown in the answer to then question linked above http://stackoverflow.com/a/4711255 `image` is a deprecated fieldkind, the behavior is identic to `Varbinary (max)`

Comment: @bummi I went through that answer, why is that SELECT statement there, can you point a detailed explanation, or a tutorial which is explaining.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63020/discussion-between-bummi-and-chathwind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1.Create FileStream with your image file.
>
> 2.Create byte array of length FileStream.Length.
>
> 3.use this byte array as value for your Pic column.

Here is good article on code project - 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354639/Storing-and-Retrieving-Images-from-SQL-Server-Us

Another solution which I can think of is, you just store the absolute disk path of your image file. You just add column of nvarchar type and use this for path.

Comment: Thanks the tutorial gave me just basic idea on how to create my concept in code. Many Thanks again.