# How can I convert a C# byte array into a binary string to be pasted in a SQL script?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Just to be clear, I'm NOT trying to insert into SQL Server directly from C#.

I'd like to convert a C# byte array into a binary string so that I can paste it into a SQL Script like the following:

```
insert into Files (FileId, FileData) values (1, 0x010203040506)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The value in your `INSERT` statement is hexadecimal, not binary.

Comment: @BACON, Thanks, I was using the terminology I read in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120749/64279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Binary constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#binary-constants) in SQL Server 'have the prefix 0x and are a string of hexadecimal numbers'.

You can convert each byte to hexadecimal using the [`"x2"` format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2) and combine the result with [`String.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__):

```
var bytes = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var binaryString = "0x" + string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
```